# Enabling TSX on OS X

Tags: kernel-extensions, macos, processor

How can I enable [TSX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions) on my Mac? The furthest I got was by trying to add a [kext](https://github.com/relan/msr.kext) that would enable me to r/w to the [model-specific register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-specific_register) but I can't install non signed kexts on my Mac. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Anything involving accessing low level features like CPU instructions is going to require kernel access. This is definitely a case of *you should know what you're doing first*, as messing with memory on the kernel level seems like it would have any number of terrible ways it could go wrong.

Assuming you do, you can [install unsigned kexts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/KernelExtensions/KernelExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH4-SW1) by disabling the System Integrity Protection.

To do so, boot into recovery mode (hold ⌘R when rebooting), open **Terminal** (in the Utilities menu), and run `csrutil disable`. Then reboot as per usual and install the kext.

Comment: I don't have access to recovery mode that is why I said "I can't install non signed kexts on my Mac". Can't I access kernel without depending on a kernel extension?

Comment: Not to the best of my knowledge. Kernel extensions are how you modify the kernel on a Mac. What's keeping you from accessing recovery mode?

Comment: I'm not the administrator. It requires password.